# Create a pseudo-property (fetched property?) over two relationships (m:n - m:1)

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have three entities:

Entity A ----- m:n ------ Entity B ------ m:1 ------ Entity C

To get the set of B's belonging to an A, I can use a.b. Since every B has only one C, I'd like to do *something* to Entity A to be able to say a.c to get the set of C's. After reading the Apple docs for fetched properties (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html), and thumbing through some fetched property questions here, this doesn't seem to be the right approach.

Can I use fetched properties to do this? Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[a valueForKeyPath:@"b.c"]`. This will hand back the value of `b.c` for every `b` in `a.b`.

More accurately, when an `NSArray` receives a `-valueForKey:` call, it constructs a new array containing the results of forwarding that `-valueForKey:` on to every element in the array. This behavior carries over to `-valueForKeyPath:` as well. So since the keypath `b` is an array, the keypath `b.c` is an array of the key `c` for every value in the `b` array.

Comment: Beauty, thanks. I just added a method to a that returns [self valueForKeyPath:@"b.c"]. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the value of `b` is a set, not an array. But `valueForKey` works for `NSSet` as well.

Comment: @MartinR: Good point. I was thinking about fetch requests so I said array, but you're right, using property access for relationships hands back a set. But as you said, `NSSet` has the same keypath behavior has `NSArray`.